# Calling a function(method) inside a class

Tags: python

I wanted to call the function spider which is within a class with the parameters such as url,word and maxPages.

when I try calling it the following way I get an error because spider() gets more than 3 arguments (it gets 4 arguments instead).

Please can someone guide me as to how I can call the function which is within a class correctly.

My code looks like this:

```
    import HTMLParser
    from urllib2 import urlopen
    from pandas.io.parsers import TextParser 

    class LinkParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    #other methods

    def spider(url,word,maxPages):
        pagesTovisit = [url]
        numberVisited=0
        foundWord = False
        maxPages = 0
        while numberVisited < maxPages and pagesTovisit != [] and not foundWord:
            numberVisited = numberVisited +1


            url = pagesTovisit[0]
            pagesTovisit = pagesTovisit[1:]
            try:
                print numberVisited, "Visiting:", url
                parser = LinkParser()
                data, links = parser.getLinks(url)
                if data.find(word)>-1:
                    foundWord = True
                    pagesTovisit = pagesTovisit +links
                    print "Success"
            except:
                print "failed"
        if foundWord:
            print "the word",word,"was found at",url
        else:
            print "word not found"


    url = raw_input("enter the url: ")
    word = raw_input("enter the word to search for: ")
    maxPages = raw_input("the max pages you want to search in for are: ")

    lp=LinkParser()
    lp.spider(url,word,maxPages)
```

Comment: Oh look I Googled your question title and found the answer... already on StackOverflow. Hmm.

Answer (score 3):

Your indentation in the post is all wrong but I assume spider is in the class. You need to add the `self` keyword as first argument to the function to make it a method:

```
class LinkParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def spider(self,url,word,maxPages):
         ...
```

Inside your `spider` method there is a call to `LinkParser.getLinks()`. Instead of creating another instance of the class you should call the method by: `self.getLinks(...)` as this won't create new instances.
Also class methods and members can be reached inside methods by writing:

```
def methodOfClass(self,additionalArguments):
    self.memberName
    self.methodName(methodArguments)
```

Comment: I know this may be FGITW but for a complete answer you will likely want to explain how to call it as well. (Really this is a duplicate but you've already answered.)

Comment: The calling of the method is not changed, he can use the rest of the code unchanged.

Comment: (I meant inside the class later will have to write `self.spider` -- perhaps out of scope for the question but it will be the next thing OP encounters.)

Comment: Oh right, I see he creates another LinkParser inside this function and uses that instead of `self.getLinks(...)`.

Comment: Thanks and I apologize for the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

*Ignoring the indentation errors which I believe are only copy-paste issues*

Every method in Python implicitly recieves the instance it is called upon as the first argument, so its definition should count for that.

Change `def spider(url, word, maxPages)` to `def spider(self, url, word, maxPages)`.

Comment: Thanks. Got it working now.